# How to fix glyphs overflowing in `<span>` elements?

Tags: css, typography

It is easy to get a text overflowing from a `<span>` element, especially (but not limited to) with italics fonts. Which I recognize it is to be expected, because the box-model sizes the element according to *advance widths* of glyphs, not their total width.

[image: A span element with box not entirely containing the text]

However, if I would like to be sure all of the pixels are inside of the box, how to do it? I tried `display: inline-block`, various suffixes to the content (after last "f") like `<wbr>` or `&#8203;` but nothing seems to work. Is there a way to "clear" the box entirely?

Comment: Show you code please what you have tried so far

Comment: There is not much to show. I made `<span>this "f" hangs over → f</span>` and then tried few things I described: various css properties for the span and for example `<span>this "f" hangs over → f<wbr></span>`. These failed attempts are not helpful at all.

Comment: I posted my answer accept please if that does work, Just to help others. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There you go this works like charm!

> Set some `padding` on `span`

```js
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59264675/how-to-fix-glyphs-overflowing-in-span-elements?noredirect=1#
```

```css
.span-txt {
    border: 1px solid;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 0 4px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="span-txt">this "f" hangs over → f</span>
```